# Required field should change focus if input field is blank

Tags: jquery

I want that if a required field is left blank then it displays an error with a red focus that this field is required. If again I clear the line and press enter then it's not showing the red focus to that field.

```js
$("*").filter(".required").on("change", function() {
  //console.log("filter change");
  var v = $(this).val();

  $(this).css("border", function() {
    if (v == "") {
      debugger;
      $(this).addClass("required");
      return "0px solid red";
    } else {
      console.log('hi');
      $(this).removeClass("required");
      return "5px solid black";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: There is really no need to do `$("*").filter(".required")`, and also expensive. Just `$('.required')` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic works, however you're setting the border displayed on error to `0px`, hence it will not be shown. If you set a visible width it will work.

That being said there's a few things you can do to improve this. Firstly select the `.required` elements directly. Selecting `*` then filtering is wasting performance. Also note that you can set the styling using a class directly using `toggleClass()` based on the length of the provided value, without needing an `if` condition. Try this:

```js
$(".required").on("change", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('error', $(this).val().trim().length === 0);
});
```

```css
input {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.error {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" required="true" class="required" />
```

Comment: For some reason your .on("change" function does not get triggered for me when testing your snippet on google chrome. I tried your snippet with .on("keyup" and this does work for me. Any idea why yours doesn't work for me? Cause I looked at the documentation and on change should be supported by inputs.

Comment: @mrdeadsven for a `change` to fire you need to type/paste something in to the field then cause a blur event on it. Then the validation will fire. You could use an `input` event instead, but this will update as the user types. It just depends on how you want it to work

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, if I may ask one last question (I'm kinda new to javascript and JQuery but I really like learning about it) is there a way for me to simulate this blur event in your snippet? I tried pasting text in the input, deleting the data in the input, cut out the data from the input but was unable to trigger the change. BTW the input event I tried, worked like charm! +1

Comment: You can use `trigger('blur')` to automatically raise an event on an element: https://api.jquery.com/trigger